# Javascript Fade In/Out Using TimeElapsed

Tags: javascript, fade

I was just wondering how would we be able to use an elapsed time function to execute a simple fade in/out function using only javascript. I hav the code as below:

```
function startFadeEffect(elem){
    var opacSetting = noOpac / 10;
    if(noOpac > 10){
        opacSetting = 1;    
    }
    elem.style.opacity = opacSetting;   
    elem.style.display = "block";
    noOpac++;
    var timer = setTimeout(function() { startFadeEffect(elem); }, 55);
    if(opacSetting == 1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        elem.style.opacity = 1;
        noOpac = 0;
        setTimeout(function() { endFadeEffect(elem); }, delay/2);
    }
}

function endFadeEffect(elem){
    var opacSetting = fullOpac / 10;
    if(fullOpac < 0){
        opacSetting = 0;    
    }
    elem.style.opacity = opacSetting;   
    fullOpac--;
    var timer = setTimeout(function() { endFadeEffect(elem); }, 55);
    if(opacSetting == 0){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
        elem.style.display = "none";
        fullOpac = 10;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have fiddle please ?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use CSS transitions?

Answer (score 0):

Because I like to make small algorithms like this, I helped you out with an example. I've made fade in and fade out functions where you can set a duration and a callback. I've commented it, so you can see how it works:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkov09n2/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="fader"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fader {
  background : #000;
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//get element to work with
var elem = document.getElementById('fader');

continuousFade();

//fade out with a 2 second duration, and then fade back in again
function continuousFade() {
  fadeOut(elem, function(){
    fadeIn(elem, continuousFade, 500);
  }, 2000);
}

//fade out function utilising the fadeTo function
function fadeOut(elem, callback, duration) {
    fadeTo(elem, getOpacity(elem), 0, callback, duration);
}

//fade in function utilising the fadeTo function
function fadeIn(elem, callback, duration) {
    fadeTo(elem, getOpacity(elem), 1, callback, duration);
}

//fade to function, where all the 'magic' happens
function fadeTo(elem, start, end, callback, duration) {
    //set the smoothness (the lower the better...)
    var stepInterval = 10;

    //get the difference from start to end opacity 
    //and get the steps in opacity needed for each interval
    var stepOpacity = (end - start) / (duration / stepInterval);

    //start the interval
    var interval = setInterval(function() {

        //add opacity to the start
        start += stepOpacity;

        //check if we already at or passed the end
        if((stepOpacity < 0 && start <= end) || (stepOpacity >= 0 && start >= end)) {

            //set the end opacity to make sure it is correct
            elem.style.opacity = end;

            //end the interval
            clearInterval(interval);

            //do the callback if it is a function
            if(typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        } else {

            //set the new opacity
            elem.style.opacity = start;
        }
    }, stepInterval);
}

//gets the current opacity from the element. If this has not set, return 1
function getOpacity(elem) {
    var opacity = elem.style.opacity;
    return opacity.length ? parseFloat(opacity) : 1;
}
```